# Changing a gameobject's rotation from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject and position and rotation are set originally as

```c#
mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-3.25f,-0.2f,0.1f);
mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,95,0);
```

Then I spin the model in swiping as

```c#
f_difX = Mathf.Abs(f_lastX - Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"));

if (f_lastX < Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"))
{
    i_direction = -1;

    if (yPos > (Screen.height*3 / 4)) {
        Swinginfo.SetActive (true);
        Swinginfo2.SetActive (false);
    } else if(yPos < (Screen.height*3 / 4) && yPos > (Screen.height / 4)){
        m_CurrentObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -f_difX);
    }
}

if (f_lastX > Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"))
{
    i_direction = 1;

    if (yPos > (Screen.height*3 / 4)) {
        Swinginfo.SetActive (false);
        Swinginfo2.SetActive (true);
    } else if(yPos < (Screen.height*3 / 4) && yPos > (Screen.height / 4)){
        m_CurrentObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, f_difX);
    }
}

f_lastX = -Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X")*1.5f;
```

The model spin.

When I want to set its initial position and rotation, I set as

```c#
mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-3.25f,-0.2f,0.1f);
mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,95,0);
```

But it doesn't change back to its initial setting.
How can I have its initial position and rotation?

EDIT:

```c#
                Debug.Log ("RangeViewScript.index "+RangeViewScript.index);
                if (RangeViewScript.index == 0) {//pass
                    mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-3.25f,-0.2f,0);
                    mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,95,0);
                    Debug.Log ("Reset 0 is called");
                }else if (RangeViewScript.index == 1) {//cheapshot
                    mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-2.6f,-0.2f,0);
                    mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,105,0);
                    Debug.Log ("Reset 1 is called");
                }else if (RangeViewScript.index == 2) {//fullswing driver
                    mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-5.0f,-0.2f,0);
                    mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,90,0);
                    Debug.Log ("Reset 2 is called");
                }else if (RangeViewScript.index == 3) {//putting
                    mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-1.9f,-0.2f,0.1f);
                    mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,95,0);
                    Debug.Log ("Reset 3 is called");
                }else if (RangeViewScript.index == 4) {//shoot
                    mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-2.75f,-0.2f,0.69f);
                    mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,100,0);
                    Debug.Log ("Reset 4 is called");
                }else if (RangeViewScript.index == 5) {//shoot
                    mainModel.transform.position = new Vector3 (-3.25f,-0.2f,0.1f);
                    mainModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,95,0);
                    Debug.Log ("Reset 5 is called");
                }
```

Comment: What is it doing instead? Is your code ever reaching these statements? Add the portion of your code where the reset to initial positions are called.

Comment: @ryeMoss  thanks, I have updated at EDIT. I printed and what it makes me confuse is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I am sure the code reaches to these statements.

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Comment: Could you try caching your initial position and rotation as variables and then reset to them instead of hard coding the numbers for initial values.